# Close event on browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

I am using a jQuery Notification on my project.

When i close the browser , i am using the `onbeforeunload` and showing a confirm box to the user.

However the client is not satisfied with the default message box ,

is it technically possible to show my Notification instead of the default one.

jQuery notification comes with a question `Do you want to close ?` and with two buttons `YES` and `No`.

When user clicked `YES` it will return `true` ,else `False`

any way to achieve ? or some comments/opinion ?

Please help me .

Thank you.

**Update :**

```
window.onbeforeunload = ShowModel;

function ShowModel()
{
    return show_pop_up();
}

show_pop_up()
{

return TRUE or FALSE ; 

}
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, you cannot cancel the close event. Imagine how annoying that would be if you could not close a tab in your browser.

Comment: @Blender Yes i understood , but trying to figure out if any chances..

Comment: Unless you are targeting IE, which probably has a hole somewhere, you're out of luck.

Comment: @Blender You mean can i do this on IE ?

Comment: can you please show us a bit of your code ?

Comment: Try to use the jQuery plugin FormNavigate that handles onchange of form input(s) to toggle on and off of window.onbeforeunload event. [link](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-plugin-form-navigation-confirmation/)

Comment: @khomyakoshka Thank you very much for the link.But i understnd the i cannot customize the defaule one.(the example is also using the defautl prompt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it technically possible to show my Notification instead of the default one.

No. You can specify the text of the message. You cannot control the buttons, you cannot control the appearance, and you cannot replace the UI with one built from scratch out of HTML/CSS/JS.

There are very strong limitations over what you can do while the user is trying to leave the page. Browsers are designed to protect users from sites that attempt to trap them (*You are trying to leave the site? NO! You are not allowed to leave until you have looked at more adverts for porn and you given us your credit card details!*).

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to show your notification instead the default. Try this:

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
 return 'Do you really want to close this window? Some your text...';
});
```

But it's true, you can't limit user's actions with browser's window.

Answer (score 0):

Technically its not possible to override the default UI.

There are two kind of page leave events can occur.

One is to navigate within the same website by clicking the links. For this kind of page unload, you could be able to write the onclick for all the menu links to show the warning message as you wish with the UI styles. But when you click links, you MUST stop the call for the beforeunload event.

The second one is to navigate outside the website using the browser buttons/address bars. Here you can't override the default UI.

The best example is Facebook. When you type the status and before submit, if you try to navigate within FB, you'll be getting a nice UI warning message. But when you close the window, you'll get the default one.

Hope this helps.